# Phonegap 3.1 local build error using command line

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm getting the following error whilst trying to build a phonegap 3 app locally.

I can complete the following. Create the app and navigate to the directory via command line.

I can then start the local build process using phonegap local build android and the next message says [phonegap] adding the android platform...

but I get the following message error message

[error] The command 'android' failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the 'android' command  added to your path. Output:

The Android SDK is v18 and installed, working correctly.

I believe it maybe an issue with my system path,

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Dano\Documents\Android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\Dano\Documents\Android-sdk\tools\

I've noticed if I type PATH in the command line its different to whats shown above...

Is there any reason this would'mt work? Any ideas please?!

Comment: Are you able to run the android command to open up the Android SDK Manager? If not, then that's a problem. If you can, then you might need to update the Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform-tools, Android SDK Build-tools, and the latest SDK Platform version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend performing the following steps exactly as stated in the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide):

To modify the PATH environment on Windows 7:

- Click on the Start menu in the lower-left corner of the desktop, right-click on Computer, then click Properties.
- Click Advanced System Settings in the column on the left.
- In the resulting dialog box, press Environment Variables
- Select the PATH variable and press Edit.
- Append the following to the PATH based on where you installed the SDK, for example:

> ;C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\tools

Save the value and close both dialog boxes.

You may also need to enable Java and Ant. Open a command prompt and type java, and also type ant. Append to the PATH whichever fail to run:

> ;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin